# Capturing search data from other websites

Tags: php, python, search, web-scraping

Is there a way to capture search data from other websites? For example, if a user visits any website with a search field, I am interested in what that user types into that search field to get to the desired blogpost/webpage/product. I want to know if this is possible by scraping the site, or by any other means. Also, is it illegal to perform a scraping operation to record such data on a third party website? Also, if this is possible using PHP and Python?

Comment: Can you explain the reason why you would want to do this? It sounds like an invasion of privacy to the end user.

Comment: Please elaborate what you mean, that question is not clear enough. From what I can understand you will not be able to view what the user is doing on other websites due to same origin policy

Comment: Unless you have your fingers in either the other site's site in any way or the user's browser, there's hardly a way to get that data.

Comment: @Sam No harm intended to anyone. This is in many ways an invasion of privacy and I have the website owner's permission to do this. Its purely for analytic purposes. However, I really wanted to do this completely from my side and not by placing a JS code or any equivalent code on the third party site.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the http referrer and see what values have been put in the GET variable, but this is restricted to GET variables ONLY!